# Flushmate 503 Installation

Tags: toilet

My brother has the same toilet that I do and is equipped with the flushmate 503 M-101526-F3.

It appears the flushmate flush valve fitting is smaller than the tank hole.

Is there an tank to toilet reducer that will allow the flushmate to be installed?

Comment: If, as you say, the two toilets are the same then the holes should be the same, NO? Even if there is an adapter it may cost nearly as much  as the correct  flush valve.

Comment: I have found that many manufacturers make the same valve for either a 2" hole or a 3" hole.